# scrollTo Paging called too fast

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, scrolltop

I am using the scrollTop function to detect how close a user is from the bottom of the screen to add more content. My javascript function is like this:

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 75) {
    var url = '<%=Url.Action("MoreView", "Status", new { id = ViewData["Id"], 
    page = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["PageNumber"])+1 })%>';

            NextPage(url); //this does an ajax call to the action method on the server

        }
```

Everything is working fine, the problem is that the window.ScrollTop >75 is happeng sometimes 2 or 3 times so fast that it loads the same content 2 or 3 times. I can probably fix this by using a session variable on the server side but didn't want to go that route because that can get ugly IMO. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now you will always be making a request to the same URL (resulting in the same data every time, unless I mis-understand what you are doing).  Once you fix that, you'll probably want to wrap your function that is called when the user scrolls in a `debounce` function (I'm using Underscore.js' `debounce` function for this example):

```
// Only call yourOnScroll once it hasn't been called
// for more than 100 milliseconds
yourOnScroll = _.debounce(youOnScroll, 100);
```

Comment: As you see in the var Url is set to Add a +1 to the current VideData[PageNumber]. In my MVC action, this VideData[PageNumber] is set to whatever the page variable is coming through. So it should be different on every render of the partial view, but since its happening too fast the partial view will have the same viewdata variable

Comment: @Jake - so you are loading this code *in* your partial view then?  (If so, are you sure that the problem is in your JavaScript, and not in your `MoreView` ... if the JavaScript is just executed on page / partial load then it can't happen more than once per load, right?)

Comment: @SeanVieira- yes I am loading in my partial view. I changed the scrollTop that fires the ajax call to be a link click instead and it works fine without loading the same data twice using click. But the click to load the page more content is old fashion and Im trying to mimick the way facebook does it.